# Windows phone 8.1 system triggered background task not registered

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to create a background task in my windows phone 8.1 app.

For some reason my system triggered background task never gets registered. I do not get an error, but the task does not appear in my lifecycle events in the debugger.

A timer triggered background task appears in the lifecycle events without a problem. i can even debug my task.

This is the code I used to register the task. It is called in the OnNavigatedTo

```
 private void registerService()
    {
        foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            task.Value.Unregister(true);
        }

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.Name = "MySampleTask";
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "BackgroundTasks.TileBadgeUpdate";
        builder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange, false));
        var ret = builder.Register();

    }
```

**BACKGROUND TASK:**

```
 public sealed class TileBadgeUpdate : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        updateBadge();
        deferral.Complete();
    }

    private void updateBadge()
    {
        var badgeXML = BadgeUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(BadgeTemplateType.BadgeNumber);
        var badge = badgeXML.SelectSingleNode("/badge") as XmlElement;
        badge.SetAttribute("value", "20");
        var badgeNotification = new BadgeNotification(badgeXML);
        BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication().Update(badgeNotification);
    }
}
```

But when I debug, I cannot trigger the event:
[image]

Any has any idea what could be causing my problem ? I get no error. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us your code regarding how you are registering your task?

Comment: I added the code in the opening post

Comment: Did you declared your task in app manifest? with timmer checked and defined entry point?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Please add the code for System Trigger as well. Also ensure you're selecting `System Event` in manifest instead of `Timer` for `SystemTrigger` to work properly.

Comment: I adapted the opening post. If the appManifest would not be OK, it would crash when registering